# Docker compose problem with volume container attachment

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker image "doc_image" and a docker volume "doc_volume". I want to spin up a container from the image where the volume is mounted into a specific point

If I do this with docker run like this:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v doc_volume:/directory doc_image
```

then it runs flawlessly (I can see the expected files in /directory in interactive way). However, when I try to spin it up with docker-compose like with a docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version '3'
services:
   my_service:
      image: doc_image
      volumes:
         - doc_volume:/directory
volumes:
   doc_volume:
```

there is nothing in /directory:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/directory/file.txt'
```

What went wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `external` property to volumes section:

```
version '3'
services:
   my_service:
      image: doc_image
      volumes:
         - doc_volume:/directory
volumes:
   doc_volume:
       external: true   # << here we go
```

Your problem is that `docker-compose` creates another volume unless you explicitly tell him to use external one. External means creates not by means of docker-compose.